# How do I dial 1 (one) in a Skype call on Linux?

Tags: skype

When you dial a Skype username with [blogtalkradio](http://www.blogtalkradio.com) it asks you to press 1 to talk to a host. You can see this behavior by trying any number on blogtalkradio. How do you press one in Linux? Skype for Linux is now up to version `4.0.0.8`. Does it have this functionality?

Comment: Can you not display a keypad in this version?

Comment: If I know what a `keypad` was, or where to hit to get it, or how to work around it not being there -- I'd not have asked the question.

Comment: I don't use Skype and I'm new to the service. I didn't like eBay, and I like Microsoft even less.

Comment: http://community.skype.com/t5/Linux/Missing-numeric-keypad-on-skype-version-4-0-0-7/td-p/797412 seems to acknowledge this issue. Not sure whether there's a real fix yet

Comment: Why are there close-votes on this?

Comment: How is it too localized? How can that ever apply for a software question? It's about a generic piece of functionality on one of the most distributed proprietary software platforms.

Comment: No, my question doesn't deal explicitly with blogtalkradio. That's an example. My question is per the title, *"How do I dial 1 (one) in a Skype call on Linux?"* Any service that requires dial-tones in conversation is subject. `Dial 1 if you would like this question read to you in French.`

Comment: So a question about `Skype on a Windows box` is not too localized, but `Skype on a Linux box` is too localized? Get out of here with the zealotry. [This is a supported platforms that Skype provides.](http://www.skype.com/intl/en-us/get-skype/on-your-computer/linux/) One of four to be exact.

Comment: There’s at least a [work-around](http://community.skype.com/t5/Linux/Missing-numeric-keypad-on-skype-version-4-0-0-7/m-p/799144#M1703) for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly, this question was asked on October 28 by me. Merely 17 days later [Skype would react to community demand](http://community.skype.com/t5/Linux/Missing-numeric-keypad-on-skype-version-4-0-0-7/td-p/797412) and put out a new version 4.1 which fixed this problem.

User interface tweaks to improve the experience

> We have tweaked the user interface a bit to improve the experience. The tweaks include:
>
> - **Hotkey "d" added to invoke dialpad during Skype-to-Skype and conference calls**
> - Pressing ESC will now exit full screen call view
> - Notification of unread messages in middle of the call
> - Differentiate between local and remote holding of call

Kudos to Skype, [find Skype 4.1 here](http://beta.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-computer/#skype-for-linux), and find the [blog entry of the 4.1 Linux change set here](http://blogs.skype.com/garage/2012/11/skype_41_for_linux.html).